# Complexity of calculating the expectation of $\operatorname{Tr} h(A)$, $A$ is a random matrix

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, na.numerical-analysis, random-matrices, rootfinding

**$A$** is a $d_1\times d_1$ random matrix. Given $\{g_i\}~(1\leq i\leq n)$ iid Gaussian variables, $f_{ij}(g_1,g_2,...,g_n)~(1\leq i,j\leq d_1)$ are degree-$d_2$ polynomials. And $f_{ij}\equiv f_{ji}~(\forall~i,j)$.   $f_{ij}(g_1,g_2,...,g_n)$ is the $(i,j)$ entry of **$A$**.  $h(x)=x^2 $ if $x>0$ and $0$ if $x\leq 0$.

The task is to calculate $\mathbb{E}~[\operatorname{Tr}(h(A))]$ with $\epsilon$ error (here for the spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix $$M=\sum_i \lambda_ie_ie_i^T, h(M)=\sum_i h(\lambda_i)e_ie_i^T.\text{)}$$

We assume that $d_1,d_2$ are constant here. **My question is**: is there a **definite** algorithm (not random) for that task such that the complexity on $n$ is polynomial (it is allowed that the complexity on $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ is very high, maybe exponential, but we don't care)?

**Maybe misleading** : I thought this way, we express every eigenvalue as a function of $\{_\}$ and thus express $ℎ()$ as a function of $\{_\}$, then calculate the expectation. However getting the eigenvalue involves solving an equation with degree maybe large than 4, thus no formulas for the roots. If we try some numeric algorithms like Newton's method to calculate the roots, we need the coefficients to be certain numbers instead of random variables.

Comment: the matrix $A$ may have complex eigenvalues, how should I interpret the requirement that $h(A)=0$ if $A\leq 0$?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker $A$ is always a real symmetric matrix see the condition:$f_{ij}=f_{ji}$, so all of its eigenvalues are real

Comment: thanks, I had overlooked the symmetry requirement; have you tried a Monte Carlo evaluation?